# Pandas wrong sorting of DateTime column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, date, datetime

I have a Pandas DataFrame df with a DateTime column ('DateTime') and a column with numeric values ('load').
I want to sort the DataFrame based on the DateTime.

Hence I used the following code:

```
df.sort_values('DateTime')
```

However, the sorting is obviously not correct (I do have entries for every hour of the year).

```
    DateTime             load
0   2017-01-04 00:00:00 52223.4500
1   2017-01-04 01:00:00 51392.4225
2   2017-01-04 02:00:00 51523.6875
3   2017-01-04 03:00:00 52356.4525
4   2017-01-04 04:00:00 54685.1125
5   2017-01-04 05:00:00 60150.9925
6   2017-01-04 06:00:00 66820.7375
7   2017-01-04 07:00:00 70047.9175
8   2017-01-04 08:00:00 71457.6350
9   2017-01-04 09:00:00 72288.9975
10  2017-01-04 10:00:00 73059.6850
11  2017-01-04 11:00:00 72965.4000
12  2017-01-04 12:00:00 71860.8625
13  2017-01-04 13:00:00 70186.3825
14  2017-01-04 14:00:00 69362.5425
15  2017-01-04 15:00:00 70146.8800
16  2017-01-04 16:00:00 71641.2275
17  2017-01-04 17:00:00 70686.6700
18  2017-01-04 18:00:00 69214.0275
19  2017-01-04 19:00:00 65552.7600
20  2017-01-04 20:00:00 62177.0875
21  2017-01-04 21:00:00 60257.1750
22  2017-01-04 22:00:00 56170.3500
23  2017-01-04 23:00:00 52265.3050
24  2017-01-15 00:00:00 46725.7725
25  2017-01-15 01:00:00 45447.4650
26  2017-01-15 02:00:00 44887.1600
27  2017-01-15 03:00:00 44230.0025
28  2017-01-15 04:00:00 43838.2300
29  2017-01-15 05:00:00 42747.1475
... ... ...
8730    2017-12-28 02:00:00 40675.2025
8731    2017-12-28 03:00:00 42022.7050
8732    2017-12-28 04:00:00 44010.7025
8733    2017-12-28 05:00:00 46842.8875
8734    2017-12-28 06:00:00 51119.2625
8735    2017-12-28 07:00:00 55059.5600
8736    2017-12-28 08:00:00 58077.6375
8737    2017-12-28 09:00:00 59538.5075
8738    2017-12-28 10:00:00 60753.6975
8739    2017-12-28 11:00:00 60720.7275
8740    2017-12-28 13:00:00 58208.7925
8741    2017-12-28 12:00:00 59299.2325
8742    2017-12-28 15:00:00 58370.4075
8743    2017-12-28 16:00:00 61120.1675
8744    2017-12-28 17:00:00 61194.5025
8745    2017-12-28 18:00:00 59644.1900
8746    2017-12-28 19:00:00 56113.4500
8747    2017-12-28 20:00:00 53672.4725
8748    2017-12-28 21:00:00 52312.3350
8749    2017-12-28 22:00:00 48750.4325
8750    2017-12-28 23:00:00 45816.2225
8751    2017-12-29 00:00:00 43684.6650
8752    2017-12-29 01:00:00 42797.5800
8753    2017-12-29 02:00:00 42608.9925
8754    2017-12-29 03:00:00 43510.8925
8755    2017-12-29 04:00:00 44424.2175
8756    2017-12-29 05:00:00 46470.2750
8757    2017-12-29 06:00:00 50801.7100
8758    2017-12-29 07:00:00 54854.4375
8759    2017-12-29 08:00:00 56226.2575
```

I think that the columns are in the correct data type:

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 8760 entries, 0 to 8759
Data columns (total 2 columns):
DateTime    8760 non-null datetime64[ns]
load        8760 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1)
memory usage: 136.9 KB
```

If I search for the min or max value in my DateTime column, I find the correct entries. Only the sorting seems not to work. What can I try?

```
df.loc[df['DateTime'].idxmax()]

DateTime    2017-12-31 23:00:00
load                    43802.8
Name: 8706, dtype: object



df.loc[df['DateTime'].idxmin()]

DateTime    2017-01-01 00:00:00
load                    43202.4
Name: 48, dtype: object
```

Comment: That looks sorted to me, is there a place where it isn't sorted ?

Comment: It starts with 2017-01-04 and ends with 2017-12-29, but as the min/max code shows, there are also records with 2017-01-01 and 2017-12-31.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an assignment issue? Try `df = df.sort_values('DateTime')` (or `df.sort_values('DateTime', inplace=True)`)

Comment: Thank you @JoshFriedlander ! This worked, so easy. However, I don't really understand, why the sorting without direct assignment did not work?

Comment: Not sure - was the output you pasted the direct result of the sorting call? If not, Pandas doesn't change the df itself

Comment: @JoshFriedlander okay, that makes sense. For the result I called the dataframe. I thought the sorting function would directly change the underlying df. Thank you for your quick help :)

Comment: Yes, it's confusing - it's a very common mistake. Happy to help!

Comment: @JoshFriedlander - consider adding an answer to this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Turning my comment into an answer as suggested by @Wai Ha Lee)

`df.sort_values('DateTime')` returns a sorted copy of the dataframe, but doesn't change the original.

That can be done either by explicit reassignment:

```
df = df.sort_values('DateTime')
```

or by using the `inplace` flag

```
df.sort_values('DateTime', inplace=True)
```

Although the latter is discouraged and slated for deprecation.